# In triangle the sum of the medians is A and perimeter is B

Tags: geometry

In triangle the sum of the medians is $A$ and perimeter is $B$. what is the relation between them
$(A) 4A<3B $
$(B) 4A>3B $
$(C) 4A=3B $
$(D) 4A \leq 3B $

Comment: To get an idea, you should try it on a few simple examples. What is the relation in an equilateral triangle? In a right isosceles triangle?

Comment: It's any traingle

Comment: No, @maxkor, Arthur is right. By considering some examples you will get rough idea of the situation. Use of equilateral triangle is preffered because data for it is easily available.

Answer (score 3):

Let K be the centroid and $m_A$ be the median through A.

[image]

Then, AK (in blue) = $\dfrac {2m_A}{3}$.

The red and green lines are similarly defined.

2(red + blue + green) = (red + blue) + (blue + green) + (green + red) > BA + AC + CB [by triangle inequality]

∴ $2(\dfrac {2m_A}{3} + \dfrac {2m_B}{3} + \dfrac {2m_C}{3}) > B$

$2(\dfrac {2A}{3})>B$

$4A > 3B$

Answer (score 0):

Since the cases given by you are valid for every triangle (as you have mentioned general case) So, for sake of simplicity, consider an equilateral triangle.

The perimeter of triangle is B so the side of triangle is B/3. On doing a little calculation, you will find that median is $\frac {\sqrt3}{2}\times \frac {B}{3}=\frac{B}{2\times \sqrt{3}}$. Sum of three medians $=\frac{B}{2\times \sqrt{3}}\times{3}=\frac {\sqrt3}{2}\times B $.

So we have:Sum of medians=$A=\frac {\sqrt3}{2}\times B$ and perimeter=$B $.

Or $4A=2\sqrt{3}B  $  and $3B=3B$. So , you get $4A>3B$. which is the required realtion.

Comment: I think we cannot decide between (C) and (D) based only on this example.

Comment: @Aretino, But taking a general example will increase the complexity very much.

Comment: @Aretino, I think the the option (C) would not hold. There is an example in my olympiad book which state this fact.

Comment: $A={3\over4}B$ is attained in the degenerate case of a "zero altitude" isosceles triangle: if its base is $b$, then perimeter is $2b$ and sum of medians is ${3\over2}b$. I think the same cannot hold for a non-degenerate triangle, but would like to see a proof of that.